# Is it possible to join a table in Sequelize without defining a relationship?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

My research suggests no. Here is a quick example of what I'd like to do.

Given 3 tables: Company, Product, Lookup...

Company has many Products. Products have one Company. Lookup table serves as an enum/constant for hardcoded values. I.e. state/country names, application specific naming conventions, etc.

Here are the models in sequelize-typescript (though the question still fully relates to sequelize js):

```
// COMPANY
@Table
export default class Company extends Model<Company> {

   @PrimaryKey    
   @Column
   Oid:number;


   @Column
   Name:string;


   @Column
   Address:string;


   @HasMany(() => Product)
   products: Product[];

}

// PRODUCT
@Table
export default class Product extends Model<Product>{

   @PrimaryKey    
   @Column
   Oid: number; 

   @ForeignKey(() => Company)
   @Column
   companyOid: number;

   @BelongsTo(() => Company)
   company: Company;

   @Column
   Price: number;   

   @Column
   Name: string;    

   //@ForeignKey(() => Lookup)    //attempt #1
   //@Column({references: {model: "Lookup", key: "Oid"}})   //attempt #2
   @Column
   LkpStateOid: number; 
}

// LOOKUP
@Table
export default class Lookup extends Model<Lookup> {

   @PrimaryKey
   //@BelongsTo(() => Product)  // do not want to hardcode Product, as it could be any table
   @Column
   Oid:number; 

   @Column
   Value:number;  // where the value represents the hardcoded state, county, etc., ie "CA"

}
```

The issue here is that there is no "real" relationship between Product.lkpStateOid and Lookup.oid, except that one references the other in order to obtain the `Lookup.value`. In any sql variant, this is not an issue- just a simple join on the tables. In sequelize, however, the relationship between the tables must be known before I can get any of the associated data in a query. This is what I'd like to do:

```
 const companyInfo = await Db.Company.find({
            include: [{
               model: Product, 
               include: [{
                   model: Lookup, 
                   attributes: ["value"]
               }]
            }]
        })
```

The first `include` is no problem. The second, nested `include` is not successful. I've tried a number of different annotations on the table, but the secondary issue (even if i could successfully "fake" a relationship in order to be able to associate the data) is that I do not want to hardcode which table the Lookup table `belongsTo` because the Lookup table could contain values that are needed in any number of other tables. Is there a way to accomplish this goal?

This link seems close to what I'd like (and is commented as an idea in the above table): http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#enforcing-a-foreign-key-reference-without-constraints
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, because Sequelize accepts literal sequel queries in the form of sequelize.query(). You can totally bypass the include[] syntax (I haven't tested this yet, but it is my understanding). Just put a raw SQL query with a JOIN statement inside sequelize.query().

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html

Comment: that is not a solution in my opinion

Comment: The question did not ask for the best solution, but simply whether it was possible. That lends itself to a very literal interpretation. In fact, it is possible.